# Qt's WebView not loading images at a random pace

Tags: windows, image, qt, iis, qwebview

Ok guys, this is driving me crazy.

I have a windows desktop application with 2 Qt's WebViews on it. They should load web pages served by an IIS web server, and everything is working fine except for the images loading. Sometimes they load, sometimes they don't, sometimes a few load, sometimes none.

Javascript preloading doesn't help.

I have the AutoLoadImages WebSetting on. Also JavascriptEnabled on.

The image files are .png files.

The file permissions are ok. If I try to load those webpages from IE or Firefox, everything goes ok, the problem is with my app.

If I try to load other websites on my app, everything goes ok, so the problem is right here and I'm not being able to solve it... any suggestions?

Comment: try to debug network requests from your app. Connect to [finished](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished)  signal of `QNetworkAccessManager` instance. To get this instance use `WebView->page()->networkAccessManager()` function

Answer (score 0):

Enable [Web Inspector support](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwebinspector.html) so you can see the network requests and replies and they are being made.

Try using another WebKit-based browser (Safari or Chrome) and watch the error console, in case something being thrown there.

Inject your own [customized network access manager](http://ariya.blogspot.com/2010/05/qnetworkaccessmanager-tracenet-speed.html) so that you can sniff the actual request.